# Calling Java from Python: "Can't find or load class" Error

Tags: java, python, eclipse, subprocess, pydev

I'm trying to call a java program from python using command line. The code is as follows:

```
subprocess.check_output(["java", "pitt.search.semanticvectors.CompareTerms", "-queryvectorfile","termvectors.bin","term1","term2"])
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class pitt.search.semanticvectors.CompareTerms
```

This happens when I run the program from PyDev (version 2.5 in Eclipse 3.7.2). However, if I run the same code from the terminal, it works and I get the result I want.

I'm almost sure that the problem is related with some configuration of PyDev and how it handles the java CLASSPATH, which is:

```
/Users/feralvam/Programas/semanticvectors-3.4/semanticvectors-3.4.jar:/Users/feralvam/Programas/lucene-3.5.0/lucene-core-3.5.0.jar:/Users/feralvam/Programas/lucene-3.5.0/contrib/demo/lucene-demo-3.5.0.jar:
```

The class "pitt.search.semanticvectors.CompareTerms" is in "semanticvectors-3.4.jar".

Any help you could give me would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: how have you checked java classpath? have you tried giving that as a command line parameter?

Comment: does `import os; print os.environ['classpath']` show any difference to the command line class path?

Comment: @user1320237 I did what you suggested and I got the following: KeyError: 'classpath'

Comment: @eis The classpath is set in the .bash_profile file. Also, if I open any terminal window and do "echo $CLASSPATH" I get the text I indicated. What do you mean by giving it as a command line parameter? Put the CLASSPATH in the "check_output"?

Comment: @Fernando giving -classpath parameter to java executable, as well as the correct classpath to go with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution proposed by @eis worked. Now, the command is:

```
subprocess.check_output(["java", "-classpath", "/Users/feralvam/Programas/semanticvectors-3.4/semanticvectors-3.4.jar:/Users/feralvam/Programas/lucene-3.5.0/lucene-core-3.5.0.jar:/Users/feralvam/Programas/lucene-3.5.0/contrib/demo/lucene-demo-3.5.0.jar:", "pitt.search.semanticvectors.CompareTerms", "-queryvectorfile","/Users/feralvam/termvectors.bin","term1","term2"])
```